# best performing dispatch on var value in clojure

Tags: clojure, clojure-java-interop

In Clojure, it is not possible to use Case forms with Vars:

```
(case (resolve 'inc) #'inc 1)
Execution error (IllegalArgumentException) at user/eval2061 (REPL:1).
No matching clause: #'clojure.core/inc
```

But I could use a hash-map or a `(condp = ...)` form instead for a readable solution.

What are some good approaches to dispatch on values of Var objects in Clojure when considering only raw performance?

Comment: Would you mind sharing the use case for this?  Also why is this tagged with Java interop?

Answer (score 4):

You could pull the symbol from the var and match on symbols instead with `case`.

```
(case (symbol a-var) clojure.core/inc 1 #_other_cases )
```

Answer (score 1):

You've listed the obvious candidates. To see which is faster for your use case, write them both up and do some benchmarking. Strangers who don't know what kinds of lookups you need to do will not have more accurate answers.

Aside: it seems kinda weird to be searching through a bunch of vars for an equality match. Are you sure you want to do that?